# missing ) after argument list with socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a code but I don't see where the ')' is missing.

```js
socket.on('modification', function () {
    $("li").remove();
    $("ul").append(
        print(
            <% todolist.forEach(function(todo, index) { 
                %>"<li><a href='/todo/supprimer/"<%= index %>"'>✘</a> "<%= todo %>"</li>"<%
            });%>
        );
    );
})
```

Can someone tell me which error I made?

Comment: You want to pass a string to `print`? What are the `<%` for? That's a syntax error

Comment: Maybe there: `});%>` ?

Comment: This code is in a Ejs document. I want to take values of an array to put it in the view. Someone told me I had to put <% %> to refer to the node code.

Answer (score -3):

Right in your first line of code after function () there needs to be a closing bracket.